# nextFocusForward skipping inputType date

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

*Android Studio 3.1.4
minSDK 23
targetSDK 27
buildTools 27.0.3*

In my Activity I have some EditText, and the user enters the necessary data and taps the right arrow on their soft-keyboard to advance to the next EditText.  My EditText are wrapped each inside an android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout..

When the subsequent EditText is inputType="date", it gets skipped, this also occurs when I have two "date"s in a row, both are skipped to the first non-date type.  I have:

```
<EditText
...
android:inputType="textPersonName"
android:nextFocusForward="@+id/input_dob"
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

but no luck, the date type gets skipped over.  Any hints as to why?

Answer (score 0):

I'm stupid, I had the flag set to false preventing focus, removed it and it works just fine

```
android:focusable="false"
```